# Configuration of custom database with openfire

Tags: sql, openfire

I am using the openfire 3.7.1. I have followed this [steps](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/45325) to configure the custom database in openfire. The main problem is that if i set the property

`provider.user.className = org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.DefaultUserProvider`

then I can login from admin portal but if i set the property like

`provider.user.className = org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.JDBCUserProvider`

then I can't be able to login with admin. So how do i set that jdbc user property ?

I am facing same problem by setting this property:

`provider.auth.className = org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider`

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? i am facing simlaar issue

Answer (score 1):

You can change the property by changing the database table `"ofProperty"` where you can insert or change your property.
Here is the Query to change your property

> update ofProperty set propValue
>   ='org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider' where name = 'provider.auth.className';

Please `restart openfire` after change.